# jquery mobile subpage does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to use jQuery Mobile subpages plugin (https://github.com/ToddThomson/jQuery-Mobile-Subpage-Widget) , so added div under 'PAGE' like this:

```
 <div class="content-view" data-role="page" id="details">

    <div id="detailsSubPage" data-role="subpage">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>
                TESTING SUBPAGE</h1>                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then outside this I have a link to the subpage:

```
   <a href="#details&ui-page=detailsSubPage" data-ajax="false" >
```

but it does not work, it opens a blank page, not showing this demo header.. what am I missing here?

Comment: This is not a jQM widget, I would contact the Github dev and ask questions

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge that is not what the widget offers.

You can not link from outside the main page directly to a sub page.

The widget enables you to ajax-load (with a nice transition) a multi-page with functioning sub pages.

Without the widget you would have to load the main page without ajax otherwise the sub page would not be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

this is the right structure: 
/div data-role="page"  class="list-view-page" id="list"/

main page content
/div data-role="subpage"  class="list-view-page" id="overview2" /

subpage content
//div close div

/div data-role="subpage"  class="list-view-page" id="overview"/
subpate content 2
//div close div

//div>//close page div